# JavaFX Draw a straight line that updates itself when the user moves the moves

Tags: java, javafx

I want to draw a straight line that updates itself, kinda like what you've in Microsoft Paint. Currently I can draw it without the visual feedback, setting the starting x and y on the first click and when user clicks the mouse button again it sets the end x and y, and adds it to root children.

I found this answer [how to draw a straight line in javafx that updates itself when the user moves the mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258465/how-to-draw-a-straight-line-in-javafx-that-updates-itself-when-the-user-moves-th), which is basically what I would like to do and essentially solves my problem by using canvas. Other user's in that thread have suggested or implicated that it would be even easier to achieve without canvas, but have not provided examples.

Since I can't comment that question: Would someone show me an example of this **without** canvas? According user comments, it should be even easier, but I can't figure it out.

I hacked together this, which works but I feel like there is a better way to do this:

```
private void registerMouseEventHandlers() {
    final Toggle toggle = new Toggle();
    final CustomLineMouseEventHandler lineMouseEventHandler = new CustomLineMouseEventHandler();

    this.scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            toggle.clickCount++;

            if (toggle.clickedTwice()) {
                lineMouseEventHandler.setEndXAndYAndAddToSceneGroup(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
            else {
                lineMouseEventHandler.setCustomLine(new CustomLine());
                lineMouseEventHandler.setStartXAndY(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }

        }
    });
}


public class CustomLineMouseEventHandler {
private CustomLine customLine;
private List<CustomLine> customLines = new ArrayList<CustomLine>();

public void setCustomLine(CustomLine customLine) {
    this.customLine = customLine;
    this.customLine.setVisible(true);

}

public void setStartXAndY(double x, double y) {
    this.customLine.setStartX(x);
    this.customLine.setStartY(y);
    LineManipulator.getGroup().getChildren().add(this.customLine);
}

public void updateLine(double x, double y) {
    if (this.customLine != null) {
        this.customLine.setEndX(x);
        this.customLine.setEndY(y);
    }
}

public void setEndXAndYAndAddToSceneGroup(double x, double y) {
    this.customLine.setEndX(x);
    this.customLine.setEndY(y);
    this.customLines.add(customLine);
    LineManipulator.getGroup().getChildren().remove(LineManipulator.getGroup().getChildren().size() - 1);
    LineManipulator.getGroup().getChildren().add(this.customLine);
    this.customLine = null;
}
```

}

Comment: what's wrong with this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42267118/1054140

Comment: @SergeyGrinev There's nothing wrong with the answer. User's who have posted in that thread, have said that it can be done WITHOUT canvas, but have not provided examples. There is nothing more or nothing less behind my request than my curiosity and desire to learn.

And of course this is a duplicate, I even posted the duplicate link to start of this thread with explanation...

Comment: oh, sorry, I mixed up with and without. To make it wi/o canvas just use `new Line` instead of `drawLine` and Pane as LayoutManager. Logic is the same.

Comment: You might want to make your question a little bit more self-contained, and only use the link as supporting information. As it stands, you need to read the other question to know what you are asking.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily implement a click-drag-release user input style for this: add a new line to a pane when the mouse is pressed, and update its endpoint when the mouse is dragged:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Draw extends Application {

    private Line currentLine ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        pane.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            currentLine = new Line(e.getX(), e.getY(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            pane.getChildren().add(currentLine);
        });

        pane.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            currentLine.setEndX(e.getX());
            currentLine.setEndY(e.getY());
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you prefer a click-move-click user experience to press-drag-release, replace the two event handlers with

```
    pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if (currentLine == null) {
            currentLine = new Line(e.getX(), e.getY(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            pane.getChildren().add(currentLine);
        } else {
            currentLine = null ;
        }
    });

    pane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
        if (currentLine != null) {
            currentLine.setEndX(e.getX());
            currentLine.setEndY(e.getY());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.